# How to filter JSON data using Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

I have json data like this

```
jsonList= [
{name:'chennai',  code:'maa'}
{name:'delhi',    code:'del'}
....
....
....
{name:'salem',    code:'che'}
{name:'bengaluru',code:'blr'}
}]
```

now i need to filter this data based on keys(name, code)and return matching values. For example if **CHE** is given, first i need to check on CODE if no values match then i need to check on NAME

```
{name:'salem',    id:'che'},
{name:'chennai',  id:'maa'}
```

I tried below code, but its not working. Each time it checks only on NAME

```
public filterJson(text){
 this.filteredOptions = this.jsonList.filter(
   e => (
    e.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1) ||
    e.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
   ).slice(0, 9);
}
```

and tried with 0

```
public filterJson(text){
 this.filteredOptions = this.jsonList.filter(
   e => (
    e.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0) ||
    e.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0)
   ).slice(0, 9);
}
```

[type script playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20jsonList%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A'chennai'%2C%20%20code%3A'maa'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A'delhi'%2C%20%20%20%20code%3A'del'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A'salem'%2C%20%20%20%20code%3A'che'%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A'bengaluru'%2Ccode%3A'blr'%7D%2C%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0Apublic%20filterJson(text)%7B%0D%0A%20return%20this.jsonList.filter(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20e%20%3D%3E%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Added%20initial%20opening%20brace%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(e.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toString().toLowerCase())%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7C%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(e.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toString().toLowerCase())%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%2F%2F%20added%20closing%20brace%0D%0A%20%20).slice(0%2C%209)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(greeter.filterJson('che'))%3B)

Comment: Sorry did typo error while posting question, updated question. Please check now. Thanks @Motti

Comment: The code still seems wrong, does your code compile? try `public filterJson(text){
 this.filteredOptions = this.jsonList.filter(
   e => (
    (e.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0) ||
    (e.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0)
   )).slice(0, 9);
}`

Comment: No luck :( still get same result. it checks on NAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me (fixing several syntax errors, one additional variable, no logic change)

```
var jsonList= [
  {name:'chennai',  code:'maa'}, // added commas
  {name:'delhi',    code:'del'},
  {name:'salem',    code:'che'},
  {name:'bengaluru',code:'blr'},
/* removed redundant closing brace */ ];

function filterJson(text) {
  const lcText = text.toString().toLowerCase(); // calculate this once
  return jsonList.filter(
    e => (
      // Added initial opening brace
      (e.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcText) === 0) ||
      (e.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcText) === 0)         
    )// added closing brace
  ).slice(0, 9);
}
```

> JSON.stringify(filterJson("che"))
>
> `"[{"name":"chennai","code":"maa"},{"name":"salem","code":"che"}]"`

Are you sure your code compiled? This is one of the main benefits of TypeScript, it checks your syntax at compile time.

Comment: Yes its seems work but NAME comes first, Code goes to last. My json file has 10,000 records. Is is possible to sort CODE first ???

Comment: @Munna it keeps the elements in the array in the same order they were to begin with (in `jsonList`) if you want to sort them you'll have to do extra work

Comment: thank you so much :) i did myself. But your fix helped me lot thank you so much again :) i update my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Answer already given by @Motti :) just want to update how to do sort, it might be helpful someone.

```
this.jsonList.filter(
      e => (
        (e.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) === 0) ||
        (e.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) === 0)
       )).sort(
         (a, b) =>
         (
          (a.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) === 0) ? -1 :
          (b.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) === 0) ? 1 : 0
        )
        )
       .slice(0, 10);
```

Comment: It really cleans up the code if you calculate `text.toString().toLowerCase()` once (and probably improves the performance a bit)

Comment: Also your code will push entries down the list if they have **both** matching `code` and `name`, you can remove the second condition in each branch. I think this is a case where having `if/else` would improve readability over the ternary operator.

Comment: @Motti please check , Updated answer, is this fine ?

Comment: Looks OK to me (without running it)